# Trying to create tiled scrolling icons, should I use GridView or GridLayout?

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, grid-layout

This is what I have so far:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dip" >
</ScrollView>
```

Inside scrollview I want a grid of icons and possibly some other views, I plan to populate those through java code.

I've looked at both GridLayout and GridView and I'm struggling to determine which is better suited, my first gut instinct was GridLayout but some people suggest GridView is better suited to my purpouses.

Comment: where do your icons come from? If your icons are from some dynamic datasource the GridView is the way to go because it works with an Adapter to populate itself.

Comment: The icons currently aren't from a dynamic source but they may eventually be from one so I'd like to plan for it.

Currently they will probably be generated from a list of strings (each string being the name of the icon or something similar)

Comment: You should use a GridView with a custom Adapter then IMO.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding

```
<Scrollable ......>
<GridLayout.....>
  your components

</GridLayout>
</Scrollable>
```

This will make your page Scrollable whatever the insider Layout